# Which are the main things to be considered when migrating from rails 1.x to rails 2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since the arrival of rails 2.3,the migration to new version became a big issue.
There might have some things to be taken care on migration.Which r those.
Any help is there and which r the advantages of this migration.

Comment: is the title of this question correct? are you asking about moving to 2.3 or 2.2? Or just about moving from any major rails version to the next one?

Comment: moving from rails 1.x to rails 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not free ($9) but Ryan Daigle's Peepcode PDF book is an excellent 80-page guide to Rails 2.1 for Rails 1 users which really helped me when upgrading from 1.x to 2.x:

http://peepcode.com/products/rails-2-pdf

Answer (score 2):

*I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278083/coming-back-to-rails/1278279#1278279) to a similar question. I recommend going there so you can see all of the other answers as well. But I'll duplicate it here for convenience.*

---

Check out the [official Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). These should provide a nice overview of Rails (if you are rusty) and are kept up-to-date with the latest versions.

You may want to check out [Ryan Daigle's Edge Rails](http://ryandaigle.com/tags/Edge%20Rails) posts which covered features as they were added to the new versions. Use the dates to determine where to start and go through each one. He also has a [PDF for $9](https://peepcode.com/products/rails-2-pdf) which covers upgrading to Rails 2.1.

I have also covered the changes on Railscasts. Check out the various tags for each version to see them: [2.0](http://railscasts.com/tags/17), [2.1](http://railscasts.com/tags/20), [2.2](http://railscasts.com/tags/22), [2.3](http://railscasts.com/tags/24).

**Update:** Thoughtbot blog has posted about [upgrading to Rails 2.1](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807004/gotchas-when-upgrading-to-rails-2-1) and [2.3.2](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805595/rails-2-3-2-upgrade-gotchas).